# Посчитать количество не сгруппированных элементов

Tags: php, sql

имеется поле type, которое содержит 4 значения (start, stop, reset, ok), для вывода я сгруппировал, а как можно посчитать количество не сгруппированных, например если есть 2 строки и в type 2 раза ok находится, что бы и выводилось 2, а не 1(так как сгруппировано)

Comment: Если нужен совет по запросу SQL - выкладывайте: название СУБД и точную версию, CREATE TABLE таблицы, INSERT INTO с примером данных, требуемый результат для этих данных с подробными пояснениями. И не забудьте свои попытки решить задачу -  составленный запрос с подробным пояснением реализованной в нём логики.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select type, COUNT(type) 
FROM YourTableName
group by type
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]